# Should a Hadith from people of Bid'at/innovations be trusted/accepted?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

Should a Hadith from someone in the chain of narration (Isnad) who practices a Bid'ah be accepted? I have heard that if it supports what he is practicing of Bid'ah then it is not accepted but if it does not support his practice it is OK.

What if he didn't create that Bid'ah/innovation, and he is trustworthy and truthful, does the practicing of this Bid'ah affect the transmission of Hadith he has?  What have scholars (looking for the views mainly of Bukari and or Muslim) said on this?

Comment: Note that, technically, someone who practises a _bid`ah_ is different from a _mubtadi`_ (the second term is much more serious and implies more)

Comment: @Ansari I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Hadiths do not originate from the person that tells you it - there is a solid chain narration that must be preserved when relating a hadith back to the Prophet SAW. In fact, if only the text of the hadith is presented to you without the chain of narration leading back to the Prophet SAW, then the hadith is considered incomplete.

If a person brings you the hadith with the proper chain of narration (the *sanad*), it is a fact - he is merely a messenger. Once he gives you the text of the hadith, the chain of narration, and the compilation in which it was found, then whatever this person said (no matter who he is, should he even be non-Muslim) can be readily proved or disproved, one way or the other.

In this day and age, most of the ahadith of the Prophet have been classified and vetted as being *sahih* (verified beyond the doubt, extremely accurate, and very reliable), *hassan* (verified and accurate), *da'if* (weak, doubt as to its authenticity), or *mauwdoo'* (known fabricated/false). This classification work was done by some of the greatest scholars of Islamic jurisprudence and history, and is preserved in their compendiums. This is what you should refer to when checking if a hadith is valid or otherwise.

Comment: @AlUmmat this would fall under the category of *'ilm elrijal* and this person's trustworthiness should have been vetted by the compilers of *ahadith* when ranking it as sahih/hassan/daif/mawdoo'.

Answer (score 0):

Some have rejected narrating from innovators, but they can be accepted if the narration and the innovator narrator meets the following:

1. The Bid'ah must not be and or lead to disbelief
2. That there is no reason to reject the narrators Hadith except for his Bid'ah
3. That it is not a caller to his Bid'ah/innovations
4. That the narration narrated does not support his Bid'ah/Innovation

And Bukari was among those who accepted narrations from those of innovations (in religion/Bid'ah), and of course with requirements.  For further information see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2w64HMQfbA), and [read this](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/131805).